# Prepend object to collection

Tags: ember.js

Instead of using `pushObject` to push an object to the end of a collection, is there a method that prepends the object to the *front* of the collection, thereby inserting the element into the DOM at the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should probably search the debug file before asking next time.

`unshiftObject()` does what I need.